# Colored boxes in C++ console

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file

I have seen many C++ and batch games that display in the console use little colored boxes that are the size of a character (█). This is an example: [C++ Tetris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdDbIdvrJIM). How can I use these in c++ and Batch. Also are they ASCII characters? I know this is extremely vague but since I don't know what they are called I can't search for them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: █ is not an ASCII character, but available in some 8-bit character sets, e.g. codepage 437. However, you can just as well use spaces and vary the *background* colour to get the same effect. Easier to write, not dependent on a particular code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [ASCII and extended ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

To print with colors in the Windows console use the [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or you can use this [cppconlib](https://cppconlib.codeplex.com/) C++ lite library that wraps that in C++ APIs.

Comment: That's quite a horrible link. There is no »single« »extended ASCII« table. It all depends on the encoding (most of which use ASCII for the lower 7 bits).

Comment: ok... but how can i use these in batch? I need fairly detailed instructions.

Comment: Just write the program in C++ and run it in the batch file.  Note that the screen buffer height and the window size height must be the same for the screen addressing to work.  Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974(v=vs.85).aspx if you want an example program.